# Trouble compiling inheritance assignment in C++

Tags: inheritance

So Ship is my base class, and I can make a Ship object fine when I comment out the lines building my child class objects. I'm not sure If I'm calling the constructors wrong or if the child classes aren't being made correctly. I just included the child class and main method in an attempt to keep the code breif

```
    class cargoShip : public Ship
        {
            public:
            cargoShip();
            cargoShip(string, int);
            void setCapacity(int);
            int getCapacity();
            void printInfo();

            private:
            int capacity;
        };




int main()
{

    Ship shipObj;
    cruiseShip cruiseObj;
    cargoShip cargoObj;

    string tempName;
    int tempYear;

    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "Please enter the name of the Ship: " << endl;
    cin >> tempName;
    shipObj.setName(tempName);

    cout << "Please enter the year the Ship was built: " << endl;
    cin >> tempYear;
    shipObj.setYear(tempYear);

    cout << "Now printing the Objects created using constructor with arguments:" << endl;
    shipObj.printInfo();

    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "Please enter the name of the Cruise Ship: " << endl;
    cin >> tempName;
    cruiseObj.setName(tempName);

    cout << "Please enter the year the Cruise Ship was built: " << endl;
    cin >> tempYear;
    cruiseObj.setMaxPassengers(tempYear);

    cout << "Now printing the Objects created using constructor with arguments:" << endl;
    cruiseObj.printInfo();

    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: The way you create the child objects looks okay. Impossible to tell if the child classes are correct without the code...

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm not getting a little red marker in the line numbers like usual when I'm getting an error. So this is only further confusing me because I can't read a description of what the error is.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I would get flamed if I put my entire code in. I wanna try to avoid getting the post closed